# Tags field returns NULL while using facebook api with php

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using the facebook php api to get the tagged images and tags of a user.I have the following user permissions :

read_stream, publish_stream, user_birthday, user_location, user_work_history, user_hometown, user_photos,friends_photos,user_about_me,user_videos,friends_actions.video,friends_video

I am able to call everything successfully and get the tagged images.However,when I call :

```
$tagged_photos=$facebook->api('me/photos');

foreach ($tagged_photos['data'] as $taggedpics)
     {
       var_dump($taggedpics['tags']); // This Returns NULL :(
       friend_id=$taggedpics['id']; // Returns some value ...
     }
```

The rest of the fields like images,id,time etc have expected values.

However,when i check `/me/photos` on graph explorer,it returns the tag.

I checked the permissions and have tried everything I could.Would really appreciate any help 
.Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never Mind ,found out my mistake . I was missing the user_photo_video_tags permission.In case this helps,Check the debug access token in the graph explorer to see what permissions you need